# Adding values from one array to another

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code for a Yahtzee game, the class I am working on takes in a certain number of dice with specified values, which is determined in the constructor. There are two arrays that are also used in this class, Available[] and Fixed[]. All the dice start off in the Available[] array, while the Fixed[] array has the same length as the Available[] array, but has 0 for all of it's values since any value that is below 1 is not used for other scoring methods.

There is one method called keep() which gives you a value, and that value should be moved from the Available[] array to the Fixed[] array. If the value given by keep is not in the Available array[] it is ignored.

I know that you can't delete values from arrays, but I do know that you can change them. I wrote a test case that calls the keep() method to keep the values 3 and 5, both of which can be found in the Available array of [3, 3, 3, 5, 6]. The problem is that when I call the method, it returns a new Available array of [3, 3, 5, 0, 0] and a Fixed array of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Instead, I want the available array to be [3, 3, 6, 0, 0] and the Fixed array to be [3, 5, 0, 0, 0]. Here is the code that I have for the keep method.

```
 public void keep(int value)
  {
  if(rolls < rollsMax)
  {
  for(int i = 0; i < Available.length - 1; i++)
  {
      if(Available[i] == value)
      {
          Fixed[i] = Available[i];
          Available[i] = Available[i + 1];
          Available[Available.length - 1] = 0;
      }
  }

  }
}
```

Specifically, I don't understand why

```
Fixed[i] = Available[i]
```

is not adding the value to the Fixed array. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the entire code:

```
    package hw3;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class represents values of a group of dice for a dice game such as Yahtzee in which 
 * multiple rolls per turn are allowed. The number of faces on the dice, 
 * the number of dice in the Hand, and the maximum number of rolls are configurable 
 * via the constructor. At any time some of the dice may be <em>available</em>
 * to be rolled, and the other dice are <em>fixed</em>.  Calls to the 
 * <code>roll()</code> method will select new, random values for the available
 * dice only.  After the maximum number of rolls, all dice are automatically
 * fixed; before that, the client can select which dice to "keep" (change from
 * available to fixed) and which dice to "free" (change from fixed to
 * available).
 * <p>
 * Note that valid die values range from 1 through the given
 * <code>maxValue</code>. 
 */
public class Hand
{
    private int[] fixed;
    private int[] available;
    private int[] values;
    private int groupDice;
    private int valueMax;
    private int rollsMax;
    private int rolls;


  /**
   * Constructs a new Hand in which each die initially has 
   * the (invalid) value zero. 
   * @param numDice
   *   number of dice in this group
   * @param maxValue
   *   largest possible die value, where values range from 1
   *   through <code>maxValue</code>
   * @param maxRolls
   *   maximum number of total rolls
   */
  public Hand(int numDice, int maxValue, int maxRolls)
  {
    groupDice = numDice;
    valueMax = maxValue;
    rollsMax = maxRolls;
    available = values;
  }   

  /**
   * Constructs a new Hand in which each die initially has 
   * the value given by the <code>initialValues</code> array.
   * If the length of the array is greater than the number of dice, the
   * extra values are ignored.  If the length of the array is smaller
   * than the number of dice, remaining dice
   * will be initialized to the (invalid) value 0.
   * <p>
   * This version of the constructor is primarily intended for testing.
   * @param numDice
   *   number of dice in this group
   * @param maxValue
   *   largest possible die value, where values range from 1
   *   through <code>maxValue</code>
   * @param maxRolls
   *   maximum number of total rolls
   * @param initialValues
   *   initial values for the dice
   */
  public Hand(int numDice, int maxValue, int maxRolls, int[] initialValues)
  {
    groupDice = numDice;
    values = new int[numDice];
    valueMax = maxValue;
    rollsMax = maxRolls;
    available = values;

    for(int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
    {
        if(i >= initialValues.length)
        {
            values[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
        values[i] = initialValues[i];
        }
    }
  }  

  /**
   * Returns the number of dice in this group.
   * @return
   *   number of dice in this group
   */
  public int getNumDice()
  {
    return groupDice;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the maximum die value in this group.
   * Valid values start at 1.
   * @return
   *   maximum die value
   */
  public int getMaxValue()
  {
    return valueMax;
  }

  /**
   * Rolls all available dice; that is, each available
   * die value in this group is replaced by a randomly generated
   * value produced by the given random number generator.
   * @param rand
   *   random number generator to be used for rolling dice
   */
  public void roll(Random rand)
  {
      rand = new Random();
      int values = rand.nextInt(valueMax) + 1;
  }

  /**
   * Selects a die value to be moved from the available dice to the
   * fixed dice. Has no effect if the given value is 
   * not among the values in the available dice. Has no effect if
   * the number of rolls has reached the maximum.
   * @param value
   *   die value to be moved from available to fixed
   */
  public void keep(int value)
  {
      if(rolls < rollsMax)
      {
      for(int i = 0; i < available.length; i++)
      {
          if(available[i] == value)
          {
              fixed[i] += available[i];
              available[i] = available[i + 1];
              available[available.length - 1] = 0;
          }
      }

      }
  }

  /**
   * Selects a die value to be moved from the fixed dice to
   * the available dice, so it will be re-rolled in the
   * next call to <code>roll()</code>. Has no effect if the given value is 
   * not among the values in the fixed dice. Has no effect if
   * the number of rolls has reached the maximum.
   * @param value
   *   die value to be moved
   */
  public void free(int value)
  {
    if(rolls < rollsMax)
    {

    }
  }

  /**
   * Causes all die values be moved from the available dice to the
   * fixed dice. Has no effect if
   * the number of rolls has reached the maximum.
   */
  public void keepAll()
  {
    if(rolls < rollsMax)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < available.length; i++)
        {
            fixed[i] = available[i];
        }
        available[available.length - 1] = 0;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Causes all die values be moved from the fixed dice to the
   * available dice. Has no effect if
   * the number of rolls has reached the maximum.
   */
  public void freeAll()
  {
    if(rolls < rollsMax)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < available.length; i++)
        {
            available[i] = fixed[i];
        }
        fixed[fixed.length - 1] = 0;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Determines whether there are any dice available to be 
   * rolled in this group.
   * @return
   *   true if there are no available dice, false otherwise
   */
  public boolean isComplete()
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < available.length; i++)
      {
          if(available[i] > 0)
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
   return true;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the values of the dice that are currently fixed (not
   * available to be rerolled) in ascending order.
   * @return
   *   values of the dice that are currently fixed
   */
  public int[] getFixedDice()
  {
    fixed = new int[groupDice];
    return fixed;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the values of the dice that are currently available to
   * be rerolled by a subsequent call to <code>roll()</code>,
   * in ascending order.
   * @return
   *   dice that are available to be rerolled
   */
  public int[] getAvailableDice()
  {
    return available;
  }

  /**
   * Returns all die values in this group, in ascending order.
   * @return
   *   all die values in this group
   */
  public int[] getAll()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            if(values[i] > values[j])
            {
                temp = values[i];
                values[i] = values[j];
                values[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return values;
  }
```

Comment: Why the `eclipse` tag ?

Comment: That was an accident, I changed it

Comment: `Fixed[i] = Available[i]` overwrites the value of the Fixed array with the value of the Available array. Did you want `+=`?

Comment: Variables in Java should begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: also, your for loop doesn't reach the last element of the available array, since you put `i < Available.length - 1`

Comment: No, I want the value of the Fixed array to essentially be replaced by the value of the Available array.

Comment: One issue also is that your method will keep all of the 3's not just one, but you are actually overriding values you may want to keep with your `Available[i] = Available[i + 1];` line

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pop out the current element and shift the rest over, but you're actually just shifting the next element over and erasing the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which way you get your fixed[] before you look at it? If through getFixedDice() from the code above, then it always return new array that initialized by default by 0.

Here is my rough version:

```
    private static int[] available = new int[]{3,3,3,5,6};
    private static int[] fixed = new int[available.length];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main.keep(3);
        Main.keep(5);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(available));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fixed));
    }

    public static void keep(int value) 
    {
          for (int i = 0; i < available.length; i++)
          {
              if(available[i] == value)
              {
                  for (int j = 0; j < fixed.length; j++) 
                  {
                      if (fixed[j] == 0) 
                      {
                          fixed[j] = value;
                          break;
                      }
                  }
                  for(int k = i; k<available.length-1; k++) 
                  { 
                      available[k] = available[k+1]; 
                  }
                  available[available.length-1] = 0;
                  break;
              }
          }
    }
```

Output:

[3, 3, 6, 0, 0]

[3, 5, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: You're right, I fixed the getFixedDice() method, along with the keep() method and now it works perfectly. Thank you!